# Variable loses characters after decimal points when added to string / passing to a file

Tags: jquery

I have the code

```
total = parseFloat($(this).find('data').attr("total")),
cnvtdtotal = total.toFixed(2),
```

Which takes the number (say, 345) and turns it into one with 2 decimals places (so, 345.00), which I then use to display in the DOM.

Further down the JS file I create a file.

When I add this to a string, and pass the string to create the file, the decimal points are lost again (so, as if I was using `total` instead of `cnvtdtotal`).

```
var file = [someOtherdata + '","' + andSomemore + '","' + cnvtdtotal +  '"',].join('\n');
```

How can I keep the 345.00 output in the file?

Comment: Please add the code where you do the string concatenation etc.

Comment: Testing the code in the question, I'm seeing "345.00" in the output.  https://jsfiddle.net/0p66831k/  Are you maybe doing some other math on `cnvtdtotal` that's converting it back into a number?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it not the code, its the program used to open it. Excel shows it wrong. Numbers shows it correctly. sorry to waste everyones time

Answer (score -1):

First off, a float has no trailing decimals, so to get those you need to turn your result into a string.

This function should do what you're looking for:

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
    var n = this, 
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
        i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))), 
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
       return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
     };
```

call it like:
`(123456789.12345).formatMoney(2, '.', ',');`

or
`(123456789.12345).formatMoney(2, '.', '');`

see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/tgdyumbd/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the toFixed method of Number object or, maybe treat the number as a string.

```
var num = 1.2353453;
num.toFixed(2); // 1.24
```

Comment: Oh didn't see that there, did you try just doing toFixed at the output instead, seems like something happens to turn it back to int

Comment: Actually this is precisely the problem, toFixed turns it into a string with so many decimal places, but going back to a number javascript automatically gets rid of trailing zeros, so you have to do toFixed where you want the output

Comment: if I put `total.toFixed(2)` in place of `cnvtdtotal ` in the `var file =` line, I get the same output (345, instead of the required 345.00)